# Plugin beforeGetUrl - not being used? (solved, facepalm)

Tags: magento2, plugin, product-urls, before-plugin

I have grouped products "containing" simple products. I have had to make the simple products visible but while I am ok for them to appear in certain lists, I want the link to go to the parent page not to the (very incomplete) simple product page.

I started by creating a helper with a new URL function and overriding the various templates to use it , but there are a lot of templates and it will be a pain to maintain.

It seems to always be `$product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, $additional)` behind all the getProductUrl so `Catalog\Model\Product\Url`  I should be able to create a "before" plugin for getUrl that swaps to the parent when it detects particular conditions.

But it seems my plugin is not happening - even when I just make it log a line then pass on things unchanged. So either I am missing an understanding or it is another class that cannot be modified?

In `app/code/Mystuff/FixGrouped/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<type name="Catalog\Model\Product\Url">
    <plugin sortOrder="1" name="FixGroupedPluginModelProductUrl" 
     type="Mystuff\FixGrouped\Plugin\Model\Product\Url" disabled="false" />
</type>
```

and in `app/code/Mystuff/FixGrouped/Plugin/Model/Product/Url.php`

```
namespace Mystuff\FixGrouped\Plugin\Model\Product;

use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url;

class Url 
{
       public function beforeGetUrl(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url $subject, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, array $params)
     {
          $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
          $logger->info('Mystuff plugin beforeGetUrl active');
          // here it would swap for parent if require
          return [$product, $params];
    }

}
```

So it changes nothing but puts a line in the log. No lines ever appear in the log.

So what am I missing?
 - i've not written it right?
 - getUrl is not called in a context that works with plugin?

I couldnt find any beforeGetUrl on this class out there so it is not reassuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **namespace** that you have in your `di.xml` and in your *class* is slightly incorrect, especially with di.xml, I don't think Magento 2 can resolve that type.

- Add **Magento** to start of type:

  `<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url">`
- Remove `\` from `\Magento` `use` (All *use* in Magento are like that);

  `use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url;`

Comment: thanks - for all my staring I did not spot that. and i have other plugin entries in that file that should have made it obvious! Now to see what the collateral damage of messing with url is...

Comment: It happens to all of us!  ( I just wonder about the `sortorder=1`... if something else might not change your result later on, just consider that)

Comment: I'd changed sort order up and down trying - at 10 it's solidly active now

Comment: Great news, I sometimes forget `sortOrder`.